# How to Track Unique Download Link

Tags: php, download, unique, analytics, tracking

I'm total beginner in PHP. I've got a file on my server, which will be updated & downloaded by my users on daily basis. The download link is unique to each user, which is checked by basic script whether the username & email exist in my database. If so, it heads to download file.

**DOWNLOAD LINK:**

```html
http://www.myserver.com/download.php?user='USERNAME'&email='EMAIL@GMAIL.COM'
```

Basically I just want to check for users which are sharing links to others on forums etc. Not sure if this can be done with Google Analytics or better option would be just simply log it to file or database.

What I'll need to track is:

1. His unique download link (or username & email)
2. IP address
3. User agent

P.S. The link is generated & accessed by user via userpanel,which is then copied & pasted to application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be pretty annoyed if you made me share my email address with everyone like that. There's also nothing stopping someone else from taking my link and sharing it around.

Comment: I know it's not the best practice,but it was done intentionally to stop sharing links. The link is generated in userpanel, which is then simple copied & pasted to the app, so no one else have access to it.

Comment: I suggest anonymizing user related information on the download link by using a token. `http://www.myserver.com/download.php?token=TOKEN`. The token can/should be a random string stored with your user information, so you can link them as needed. For the token generation you could use PHP built-in functions like `uniqid()`.

Comment: You basically answered your own question. 1. Validate user's credentials (at best a token as already commented). 2. Provide file and track download in GA (how to see e.g. https://www.jeffalytics.com/track-downloads-google-analytics/). What exactly is your question: How to validate user permissions or how to track downloads in GA?